# Oracle PLSQL regexp_substr separate comma separated string with double quotes

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I've seen examples of how to separate comma-separated strings into rows like this:

```
select distinct id, trim(regexp_substr(value,'[^,]+', 1, level) ) value, level
  from tbl1
   connect by regexp_substr(value, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
   order by id, level;
```

but, my question is, how do I do this on double quote and comma delimited strings?

Ex:  the above works for strings like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7", but what about "1","2","3","4,5","6,7,8","9" so that the rows end up like:

1
2
3
4,5
6,7,8
9

edit:  I'm on Oracle 11.2.0.4, 11gR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hack. Replace the pattern "," with # and use it in regular expression.It works like a charm.

Input String : `"1","2","3","4,5","6,7,8","9","Ant,B","Gradle","E,F","G"`(Can be number/Character doesn't matter)

```
 with temp as  (
       select  replace(replace('"1","2","3","4,5","6,7,8","9","Ant,B","Gradle","E,F","G"','","','#'),'"') Colmn  from dual
     )
SELECT  trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^#]+', 1, level)) str
  FROM (SELECT Colmn str FROM temp) t
CONNECT BY instr(str, '#', 1, level - 1) > 0
```

Output :

```
    STR
1
2
3
4,5
6,7,8
9
Ant,B
Gradle
E,F
G
10 rows
```

Refer DBFiddle link for demo.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d09c326f614d10f5d3c407fdfd3a44c5

Comment: Appreciate your input, but the numbers were just an example.  Unfortunately, the real data is not numeric.

Comment: I tried it and it just returns empty spaces, it doesn't separate the list.

Comment: Refer Dbfiddle link for demo, i have updated the answer with the link.Not sure why it is n't working for you. Could you share exact data you are using for testing and update to the question.

Comment: I missed the replace '","' with #, that did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is the another solution.it must be working all string with have number.
i used number values index as base.

```sql
with temp as  (
       select  '"1","2","3",x"4,5","6,73,8","9"' Colmn  from dual
     )
SELECT   regexp_substr(Colmn, '\d{1}', REGEXP_INSTR(Colmn, '\d{1}', REGEXP_INSTR(Colmn, '\d{1}') ,level),1 )   from temp
CONNECT BY REGEXP_COUNT (Colmn,'\d{1}')+1> level
```